# What about QR codes?

Tags: discussion, qr-codes, market

I just used QR codes to link to apps in the market.

What's your opinion on using them for linking apps? I think they are widely used, and there are many barcode readers for Android which can handle them, and it is better than searching the market for an app by yourself. So is it ok to use them to link apps?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I find QR links very useful, especially when there are no many barcode scanners around.

However, There should be a standard for these "Here is an App that will help" posts, just so we aren't A) leaching images, B) not shutting out users who want to see the app without having to go to the market place.

Below, I've listed the way I've been linking apps to answers, including how not to leach images (IMPORTANT) because we don't want to get in trouble, now do we?

---

For QR images, I've been using the following method:

1) Find the app on (marketplace e.g. AppBrain) you want to share
[image]

2) Find the QR Code button, and locate the QR code.
[image]

3) Copy the URL of the QR code
[image]

The URL is
`http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=market://search%3Fq%3Dpname:com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.appsBlockquote`

Which is basically

`http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=150x150&chl=LINKHERE`

If you use the Image upload tool on the post answer, you can use the image URL to reupload the image to imgur.com
[image]

That way, you get the right QR code, generated from a reliable source, and you don't steal bandwidth.

4) MAKE SURE YOU HREF LINK TO APPBRAIN AT THE SAME TIME
So annoying when you get a QR link, and no web reference to what it is

(I'm not sure what other services use, I use AppBrain for a lot of my stuff, but if you know the marketplace URL, just go from step 3 and hardcode the charts.api link yourself)

(Freehand circles)

Comment: I take that as a "yes", then?  ;)

Comment: I seem to have lost half of my post. Shall update with my actual logic now <_<

Answer (score 5):

Any thought about actually including a QR code generator in the Android SE text editor itself?

That way, we can

1. be sure we're not leeching
2. enforce that the QR code is also linked to the URL itself

Comment: +1 I agree something like typing ~~~appname-or-url-here~~~ should be converted into a hyperlinked QR code

Comment: Definitely a good idea but you have to have either the package name in order to generate a *good* Market URL which will take the user straight to the app page or if you don't have that then the app name will allow you to generate a Market Search URL.

Answer (score 2):

QR codes are great.  Just make sure to also make the images a link to what the QR code is pointing to (for people who are browsing this site on their phones).

There is also [an ASCII QR code generator](http://asciiqr.com/), but not sure how well they'd work here.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we have [Android Web Market](https://market.android.com/), do we still need QR?

PS: should this be a separate question?

Comment: It kind of almost already is ;) http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/310/qr-code-generator